# Understanding Get Method Overrides

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am totally new to Web API an am not understanding how to Filter get calls.

This method returns all items in my database.

```
// GET: api/LogEntries
public IQueryable<LogEntry> GetLogEntries()
{
    return db.LogEntries;
}
```

This method returns a specific item in my database.

```
    // GET: api/LogEntries/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(LogEntry))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetLogEntry(int id)
    {
        LogEntry logEntry = db.LogEntries.Find(id);
        if (logEntry == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(logEntry);
    }
```

So now I want to filter the returned records so I created this method but it won't work because the specific item method gets called.  I seem to be missing a concept and am hoping you can point me to more clear understanding.  Thanks

```
// GET: api/LogEntries
public IQueryable<LogEntry> GetLogEntries(string levelID)
{
    int levIdInt;
    if (Int32.TryParse(levelID, out levIdInt))
    {
        return db.LogEntries.Take(300).Where(l => (int)l.Level == levIdInt).OrderByDescending(d => d.TimeStamp);

    }

    return db.LogEntries.Where(i => i.ID < 0);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the route for that method

```
[Route("api/LogEntries/Level/{levelID}"]
public IQueryable<LogEntry> GetLogEntries(string levelID)
{}
```

More on routing is available here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: You can also access this api (without adding any routes) using:

 /api/LogEntries?levelId=TheLevel

Adding a route allows you to shape the API differently and make the data part of the url and not part of the query.